# KeyError: 'Spider not found: ... " in Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: scrapy, cloud9-ide

I read threw a couple other similar Stack Overflow threads on people having similar issues with running their spiders but I think my setup on Cloud 9 IDE is a little different or I missed something. Here's my tree:

```
    mikeumus@scrapy-phishtank:~/workspace $ tree
.
├── README.md
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── scrapetank
│   ├── scrapetank
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   ├── pipelines.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   └── spiders
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __init__.pyc
│   │       ├── wellsfargo_offline.py
│   │       └── wellsfargo_offline.pyc
│   └── scrapy.cfg
└── scrapy_phishtank
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc

4 directories, 22 files
```

and here's what I get when I run `scrapy crawl wellsfargo-offline` from `/scrapytank`

```
mikeumus@scrapy-phishtank:~/workspace/scrapetank $ scrapy runspider wellsfargo_offline                                     
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: File not found: wellsfargo_offline

mikeumus@scrapy-phishtank:~/workspace/scrapetank $ scrapy crawl wellsfargo_offline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
    spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 44, in create
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: wellsfargo_offline'
```

Not sure what's wrong. Thanks for any help. :)
Here's the link to my C9 IDE: 
https://ide.c9.io/mikeumus/scrapy-phishtank

Comment: Did you set the name of the spider to `wellsfargo_offline` in the code? `name = 'wellsfargo_offline'`

Comment: he he, twas up too late. Thanks @marven

Comment: You start the spider with `scrapy crawl spidername` if it's implementation is distributed in the projects. `scrapy runspider` is for a self-contained spider scripts.